# Solving pde with homogenous neumann boundary condition using fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

I have the following diffusion problem:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = -Cu,\;\; 0 \leq x \leq L, \; t\geq 0,\\
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0, t)= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(L, t)=0,\; t\geq0,\\
&u(x,0)= \begin{cases} 
      u_0, & 0<x<d \\
      0, & d<x<L
   \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Since we have homogenous Neumann boundary condition I make the ansatz:
$$u(x,t) = C_0 + \sum _{k = 1} ^{\infty}\beta_k(t)\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{L}x\right),$$
and with the pde I have:
$$\sum _{k = 1} ^{\infty}\left(\beta'_k(t)+D\frac{k^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\beta_k(t)\right)\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{L}x\right)=-CC_0 - C\sum _{k = 1} ^{\infty}\beta_k(t)\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{L}x\right).$$

And this is where I am stuck. The constant $-CC_0$ seems to cause trouble. Without it I would just solve
$$\beta'_k(t)+D\frac{k^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\beta_k(t)\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{L}x\right)=-C\beta_k(t)$$
to find $\beta_k$, but with the constant I am not sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then don't include the constant $C_{0}$, just start the summation at $k = 0$. Or make the transformation $u = e^{-Ct} v$ first and then solve the new problem in $v$.

Comment: So make an ansatz without $C_0$ or just not include the constant in the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

Try using separation of variables. Assuming solutions
$$
         u(x,t)=X(x)T(t).
$$
Substituting into the equation gives
$$
          X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)=-CX(x)T(t)
$$
Dividing by $X(x)T(t)$ gives
$$
             \frac{T'}{T}-\frac{X''}{X}=-C \\
             \frac{T'}{T}+C=\frac{X''}{X}
$$
So there is a separation constant $\lambda$ such that
$$
             \frac{T'}{T}+C=\lambda,\;\; \lambda=\frac{X''}{X}.
$$
The endpoint conditions for $X$ on $[0,L]$ have the form
$$
             X'(0)=0,\;\; X'(L)=0.
$$
The $X$ solutions have the form
$$
             X(x)=A_n\cos(n\pi x/L)
$$
with corresponding values of
$$
            \lambda_n = -n^2\pi^2/L^2,\;\;n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The related solutions in $T$ are found by solving
$$
          \frac{T'}{T}=-n^2\pi^2/L^2-C \\
              T(t) = \exp\{(-n^2\pi^2/L^2-C)t\}
$$
The general separated solution becomes
$$
        u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\cos(n\pi x/L)\exp\{(-n^2\pi^2/L^2-C)t\}
$$
The constants $A_n$ are determined by the initial condition
$$
             u(x,0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\cos(n\pi x/L).
$$
The coefficients in this expansion are Fourier coefficients of $u(x,0)$ with respect to the basis functions $\cos(n\pi x/L)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. The function $u(x,0)$ is given in the problem. So the $A_n$ are known; they are the Fourier cosine coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Try using separation of variables. Assuming solutions
$$
         u(x,t)=X(x)T(t).
$$
Substituting into the equation gives
$$
          X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)=-CX(x)T(t)
$$
Dividing by $X(x)T(t)$ gives
$$
             \frac{T'}{T}-\frac{X''}{X}=-C \\
             \frac{T'}{T}+C=\frac{X''}{X}
$$
So there is a separation constant $\lambda$ such that
$$
             \frac{T'}{T}+C=\lambda,\;\; \lambda=\frac{X''}{X}.
$$
The endpoint conditions for $X$ on $[0,L]$ have the form
$$
             X'(0)=0,\;\; X'(L)=0.
$$
The $X$ solutions have the form
$$
             X(x)=A_n\cos(n\pi x/L)
$$
with corresponding values of
$$
            \lambda_n = -n^2\pi^2/L^2,\;\;n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The related solutions in $T$ are found by solving
$$
          \frac{T'}{T}=-n^2\pi^2/L^2-C \\
              T(t) = \exp\{(-n^2\pi^2/L^2-C)t\}
$$
The general separated solution becomes
$$
        u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\cos(n\pi x/L)\exp\{(-n^2\pi^2/L^2-C)t\}
$$
The constants $A_n$ are determined by the initial condition
$$
             u(x,0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\cos(n\pi x/L).
$$
The coefficients in this expansion are Fourier coefficients of $u(x,0)$ with respect to the basis functions $\cos(n\pi x/L)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. The function $u(x,0)$ is given in the problem. So the $A_n$ are known; they are the Fourier cosine coefficients $A_n$ in the cosine series expansion of $u(x,0)$.